# Current route not reload when click on link

Tags: angularjs

I'have a small angularjs app and small routing problem.

`$routeProvider.when('/accounts', {templateUrl: 'app/partials/accounts.html', controller: 'accountsListController'});`

`a href="#/accounts"`

Here is my controller;

```
appControllers.controller("accountsListController", function($rootScope, $scope, accountsService, Page){
    $scope.$emit('START_LOAD');

    Page.setTitle("Hesaplar");

    $scope.status;
    $scope.accounts;

    getAccounts();

    function getAccounts() {
        accountsService.getAccounts()
            .success(function (accs) {
                $scope.accounts = accs.accounts;
                $scope.$emit('STOP_LOAD');
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load accounts data: ' + error.message;
            });
    }

});
```

When i first click /accounts link, my controls, rest requests... everything loaded perfectly. But, on the same route, i reclick /accounts link again, nothing reload or triggered.

All routing requests work one time, not refresh, sample fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/munsal/BUg8L/11/

Where I'm doing wrong?

(I'm sorry for my english is bad)

Comment: can u give controller code

Comment: Sorry, I've added my controller code now.

Comment: can u put code on jsfiddle/plunker

Comment: My fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/munsal/BUg8L/10/

Answer (score 1):

I updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BUg8L/14/). Does it work the way you want?
I only added `/` at the end of urls in `$routeProvider`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, thats fix it. But, this method, create route change request two times. Here is my updated js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/munsal/BUg8L/18/

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
 $scope.$emit('START_LOAD');
 $scope.$emit('STOP_LOAD');
```

and try

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the problem continues for removing these rows or empty(only console.log writing) controller.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question. Solution is using angularjs ngHref directive.

Web page: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngHref